# available variables for NGINX

Tags: nginx

I want to serve a raw file if it's being hotlinked, but rewrite the url if someone is visiting the file in their browser.

I've seen this hotlinking example a few times:

```
location /pictures/ {
   valid_referers none blocked mywebsite.com *.mywebsite.com;
   if ($invalid_referer) {
      return   403;
  }
}
```

BUT, how can I refer to valid referers? I'm trying to serve the raw file requested if it's being linked to from another page (hot linked).

If someone is viewing that file in a browser, I want to add some HTML (i.e. rewrite to another URL);

What variables are available other than `$invalid_referer`?

I've tried:

```
if( !$invalid_referer){
    return 403; #allow hot-linking only;
}
```

And can see no mention of other available variables in the documentation. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the value of **$invalid_referer**

From the [Documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html#valid_referers):

> Specifies the “Referer” request header field values that will cause the embedded $invalid_referer variable to be set to an empty string. Otherwise, the variable will be set to “1”. Search for a match is case-insensitive.

```
if($invalid_referer = ""){
    return 403; #allow hot-linking only;
}
```

you could also do

```
if($invalid_referer != "1"){
    return 403; #allow hot-linking only;
}
```

Comment: The first answer solved my problem. Did not try the second one.